# "/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory" when compiling HTK

Tags: 20.04, gcc, make, makefile

I'm trying to compile the [HTK library](https://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/docs/inst-nix.shtml), but run into issues:

```
$ make all
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
  || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/<path_removed_for_privacy>/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG -UPHNALG  -c -o HGraf.null.o HGraf.null.c
In file included from HShell.h:40,
                 from HGraf.null.c:25:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Running `dpkg -S libc-header-start.h` tells me:

```
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
```

Ok. `/usr/include/bits` should be a symlink to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits`, but running `dpkg -S /usr/include/bits` gives me:

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/include/bits
```

I have researched this error, and from what I can understand I ought to install `gcc-multilib` to resolve it. But I run into problems with this too:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-multilib : Depends: gcc-9-multilib (>= 9.3.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Trying to install `gcc-9-multilib` gives further and further dependency problems. Researching this, I found [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=353624) thread, where they solved the gcc-multilib issue, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I get the same dependency issues as in the original post. Their solution was to downgrade `libc6-dev` running "`sudo apt install libc6-dev=2.31-0ubuntu9.2`". When I do this, it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.2).
libc6-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I already have the version that resolved their problem, but my problem remains.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this, and most of all get the HTK library running would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**:
As requested in the comments: `apt policy gcc gcc-multilib gcc-9-multilib`:

```
gcc:
  Installed: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gcc-multilib:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
gcc-9-multilib:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Version table:
     9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     9.3.0-10ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please include the output of `apt policy gcc gcc-multilib gcc-9-multilib`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the original post.

Comment: Thanks - tbh I can't see why gcc-multilib won't install. However I'm curious why it is attempting to build a 32-bit version in the first place?

Comment: HTK is 32bit only? `./configure` will create a Makefile with `CFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) -m32 ...` ...... Example htk : `htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb` (Feb 28 2018) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Di29AvqoRBEJ4haW2nusPT1wMPkE14B1/view?usp=sharing ... Installs OK into a clean Ubuntu 20.04, with all the i386 dependencies ( `sudo gdebi htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb` ).

Comment: It appears that somebody found a solution for 64bit  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/htk/  →  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-4175557896/page2.html , post #23 ...... Simply delete `-m32` flags in relevant `Makefile.in`s (Makefiles) or in `configure` .... and `export CC=gcc-4.8 && ./configure && make all`

Comment: Thank you so much, Knud! 
The second suggestion is far better than downgrading to 32 bits.
Removing the -m32 flags (albeit using my default gcc (9.3.1)) resolved the installation errors. The library seems quite buggy in general though, with heaps of warnings; I'll need to look into if they cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

i came across this and it worked

https://wiki.crowncloud.net/?How_to_Install_GCC_on_Debian_11

after installing the gcc,
go to terminal and type

gcc filename.c
./a.out

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1272644)